# How to move discord users with no role (@everyone) to an existing role with my .js bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am already using this `"guildMemberAdd"` for the members recently added to join "Visitors" role.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member =>{
  member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Visitors"), "auto added.");
})
```

My bot can't be online 24h. So when I connect it, there are some users who joined meanwhile the bot was offline, obviously with no role (I guess they are in @everyone role).

My intention is to move discord users with no role to an existing role when I connect the Bot.

Answer (score 0):

In your ready event, just fetch every member in the guild with [`GuildMemberManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch), and then filter through members with only one role (@everyone).

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
 const members = await client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID').members.fetch(); // fetch every member
 members
  .filter((m) => m.roles.cache.size === 1) // iterate through every member with only one role
  .each((m) => m.roles.add('Role ID')); // add the Visitors role
});
```

Comment: Very helpful for going on, but it seems to be an error when iterating; "members.each is not a function at Client" & "members.filter is not a function at Client" .Is there any update in the documentation that causes that maybe?

Comment: That's my mistake, please check my edited answer

Comment: That's it. Now I will add a message.send on the same client.on to let the users know where and why were moved.